# How long, on average, is a good response to a written exam question?

Tags: exams

I've always assumed that the "blue book" exam answer booklet should contain answers to midterm or finals questions that are about one or at most, two, paragraphs long. In other words, you cannot expect a student to write full fledged essays on every question formatted in the form of head-body-conclusion. Now I'm not so sure; maybe while it should not be nearly as long as an essay assignment, it should have the format of head-body-conclusion in the least?

As an aside, do professors make it clear on the exam paper instruction section how long the responses should be for "longer response" type questions, before the students ask how long they should be?

Comment: That really depends on the instructor. If we say one thing she/he/they another, then which opinion counts? So if it is not clear, just ask your instructor.

Comment: This question in the title is literally a case of "how long, on average, is a piece of string".

Answer (score 2):

The average, though it exists, is meaningless in practice. It gives no guidance to either a professor or a student.

I can think of several independent axes on which there is variability including the individual professor, the field, the time allotted, the number of questions, the marking/grading criteria, and probably more.

In the extreme, an exam might have a single question allotted over three hours. At the other, twenty questions and an hour. (Maybe not the *most* extreme, actually). On another axis, an exam might have twenty questions with instructions to pick one to answer. Lots of possibilities, many not typical.

A professor *should* give some idea of the expectations, but not all do. If you are the professor, I suggest that you do that. If you are a student you could ask, prior to the exam, what might be expected.

Without guidance, if you are the student, try to capture the most important elements of the answer in the first paragraphs - sort of like the "newspaper style". Without guidance, try to say something useful about each question.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the average would mean adding up a random sample of exam questions and then dividing. I suppose this could be done, but it would be similar to the guy who said that "On average, Switzerland is at sea level. Throw the mountains into the lakes and it all balances out."

I think it is perfectly reasonable to expect a student to write an essay that has head-body-conclusion, or some similar structure. But the professor should account for the amount of time and the number of questions.  One part of university level learning is, indeed, learning how to structure things this way, relatively quickly (and that is so across disciplines, I think).

But there is doubtless wide variation across disciplines and within disciplines. There are surely examples where anything less than a couple pages would be ridiculous. And other cases where writing more than one paragraph would be silly. And, while guidance from the professor would be nice (especially in intro level courses), part of what you should learn is how to tell what a reasonable length answer is.

(And some professors give guidance in terms of how much the answer is worth.)